# Oracle - Search a string containing underscore char without using Escape

Tags: oracle

I have below queries and the time taken by each query.

Query

```
select id from test_table where mail_address like lower('a_bcd%');
```

Time Taken : More than 5 mins !!

```
select id from test_table where mail_address like lower('a/_bcd%') ESCAPE '/';
```

Time Taken : Less than a second

**Question:** 
Is there a way to improve performance of first query without using ESCAPE in the query ??

Comment: Are you aware that `_` is a wildcard thus both queries are *not* equivalent? What makes `ESCAPE` unsuitable for your purposes?

Comment: What is the reasoning for not wanting to use the `ESCAPE` clause if that is solving your problem?

Comment: The two queries are very different in their expected results, so it's meaningless to compare their performance. They're apples and oranges. Work out what exactly the query should do, *then* start comparing apples with apples to get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that:

- You have *many* rows
- Your `mail_address` column is indexed

For that reason, filtering by a given prefix is lighting fast (since it can make use of the index) while searching for some random expression will necessarily require a full table scan.

Oracle provides [function based indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS005). If you *really* need to find records where second character can be any, that'd probably be your only chance.

*P.S. I suppose this isn't your real query but `a_bcd%` is never going to get more lowercase ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from test_table 
where mail_address >= 'a_bcd' 
  and mail_address <  'a_bce'
```